# Root directory of hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, symbolic-link

I installed a second hard drive, I can access its root folder it through `/media/very-long-name`, where very-long-name is a string of 32 hexadecimal characters separated by hyphens, it is not practical to navigate to it and I think it may cause bug since I want to send files across networks

My question is if like in Windows, where it would be something like D:\, does it have a second shorter name (I tried sda sdb but the shell tells me they are not directories )

Comment: please run `sudo lsblk -flp` from terminal and post the result into your OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a symbolic link from this long name to a short name

Symbolic link can be created using `ln -s`

If you like to call this disk /media/D you can:

```
sudo ln -s  /media/very-long-name /media/D
```

And from now on, you'll be able to access the disk also using `/media/D`

[man ln](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ln)

> **ln** - *make links between files* 
>   -s, --symbolic  - *make symbolic links instead of hard links*

Comment: ehm. He probably wants to auto-mount it so an edit of /etc/fstab might be more correct as an answer. The long-name is probably the UUID so the mountpoint would be setup in /etc/fstab.